# Is credential necessary when running Firebase Admin with Firebase Emulator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, firebase-cli, firebase-tools, functions-framework

I'm running Firebase Admin SDK on python through functions-framework with Firebase emulator set up on different terminal and I have a question.

While this works on shell(zsh)...:

```py
# python
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth as admin_auth, firestore as admin_firestore, credentials

app_options = {'projectId': 'dev-some-project'}
firebase_admin.initialize_app(options=app_options)
db = admin_firestore.client()


def change_order_state(request):
    return 123
```

```sh
# shell
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 \
FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099 \
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./path_to_credential.json \
functions_framework --target=change_order_state --port=1234
```

but this, without `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, doesn't work on shell:

```sh
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 \
FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099 \

functions_framework --target=change_order_state --port=1234
```

The error log says:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:
Could not automatically determine credentials.
Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or 
explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.
```

Is it able to run Firebase Admin with Firebase emulator without setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? I don't see the necessity for setting credential when running it on emulator.

Or any other solutionn is okay. I saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726082/do-i-need-a-firebase-service-account-when-i-only-want-to-use-the-emulator) and this solution is okay as long as it can be written with Python.

The reaoson why I don't want to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is that I dont want to distribute credential file to ALL developpers, it's too heavy for the initial development stage.

[optional]
...and if it's not possible to run without credential, what is the minimum GCP role for giving developper when runnning Firebase Admin SDK on local machine with emulator. Firebase Admin role seems too strong for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need functions-framework with the Firebase emulator?  The emulator will run your function code in response to a triggering event, and that event can happen through a simple HTTP call.  [Functions framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework) is for standalone local testing of Cloud Functions code without the firebase-function library and CLI.

Comment: Thanks. I need to run some function with python. Firebase function can’t handle python. That’s why I’m using functions-framework.

Comment: You might then want to show the code that isn't working the way you expect so we can see what you're trying to do.  That part could be wrong, and we can't tell.

Comment: Thanks I added the code as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes some credentials are necessary as it looks for credentials and applies DefaultCredentials function and you got DefaultCredentialsError.

but you can use *AnonymousCredentials* class

```
from google.cloud import firestore
from google.auth import credentials

client = firestore.Client(credentials=credentials.AnonymousCredentials())
```

Comment: Is there a javascript equivalent for this?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

Comment: ok i was hoping for a way to provide dummy credentials to the admin sdk when using the emulator, but it looks like this is a web client only thing.